# Assigning Role Definition to SharePoint Site group through Flow?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-api, power-automate

I'm currently in the process of trying to automate SharePoint site creation, and am looking at doing so with MS Flow, MS Graph, and the SharePoint API - I've created a new role definition permission level - Limited Read (Which is just 'Read' minus the ability to view versioning information) for the client site, and a new client site group titled "Client Users", to go alongside Owners, Members, and Visitors. However, I'm not 100% sure about how I'd actually go about assigning the permission level to the sitegroup itself? I know through PowerShell I'd just use the Set-PnPGroupPermissions cmdlet and the -identity/-addrole params, but I'm not clear on how to do it through Flow - I'm currently giving it a shot through a HTTP action and am getting the below error, I'm guessing it's my authorization or possibly my URI, but I don't even know if I'm using the right action to be honest:

**{"error_description":"Invalid issuer or signature."}**

See Flow below:

[Flow 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGm82.png)

[Flow 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ViFw.png)

[Flow 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP4rW.png)

[Flow 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjibr.png)

[Flow 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwnWA.png)

[Flow Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhh0P.png)

Any help would be appreciated! Alternatively if someone could just point me in the direction of a guide detailing how to assign a role definition to a site group through Flow, I'd be most appreciative!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working, turns out I was just using the wrong action. Went with 'Send HTTP request to SharePoint' instead of the HTTP action and it worked first time.

[Flow 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkmGW.png)

[Flow 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDNZC.png)